# is it good to edit the question's title that is unrelated to question?

Tags: discussion, title, editing-help

I read a title and click to read and solve if i could but i find that the actual question is not that and is unrelated to the title, Is it appropriate to edit the title?

Comment: Yes. Note that since you don't have 2K edit privileges yet you should provide reasonable explanation to the edit for reviewers.

Comment: So please don't fix *just* the title. Do everything you can on the entire post - code ticks where appropriate, remove rambling preambling, "thanks in advance" et cetera. (Oh wait, I see you already did so on a couple of posts. Thank you for editing!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Edit away. A bad title can make searching difficult.

Just make sure that you put in a good enough edit comment so that reviewers can see ***why*** you made the changes you did.

Also, try and fix as many issues with the whole question as you can, to prevent the edit from being rejected as too minor.